# How to select a record from coredata by id with MR in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I have stored in Core Data one list of cars, each car has a specific `id`.

I want to select that car which has `id=2`.

I have used MagicalRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the negative comment, but how come you've chosen to use a third-party tool, but haven't read far enough in the documentation to even work out how to read a record back from the database ?

Surely this is the *absolute basics* of using MagicalRecord ?

Perhaps this'll help:

[MagicalRecord with Objective-C](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios)

Personally, I use `mogenerator` with Objective-C, and with that, I can read a record from a CoreData database in one line of code:

```
Car* selectedCar = [Car findObjectWithID:@"id" PKvalue:carID];
```

The `mogenerator` library, and how to use it easily, is nicely described on the following page.  It's 4-years-old, but CoreData is so horribly painful today (in XCode 6.3), that it's still invaluable today.

[Super Happy Easy Fetching from CoreData](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/13/super-happy-easy-fetching-in-core-data/)

Hope this kinda helps.